# Magento - Create a structure block for the home page

Tags: layout, magento, magento-1.4

I would like to create a structure block (or reference) for my home page magento, on full width of the page to put a welcome text and a banner in it, under that I want to create a design with 3 blocks.
What is the best way to do this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As usual, create your extension and add a block , layout and template to it and reference it to place that suits you most. If you don't want to make extension then add the references to CMP/pages part of magento by customizing the home page for example

Comment: I have tried to make without extension like this tutorial: 
http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/custom-reference-structural-block/
but it have not worked. I think that I have to create another structural block, but I don't know why it don't works.

Thanks for more clarifications about adding new references to CMS/pages.